# Can't boot after lubuntu-desktop environment

Tags: unity, 18.04, nvidia, lubuntu, encryption

I have two problems.

**Problem 1** : My old laptop is running Ubuntu 18.04 (Unity). I was trying other desktop environments like Gnome yesterday, and I wanted to try Lubuntu, so I installed it using this command :

sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop

When it got installed, it was running fine. But after a reboot - after showing "Lubuntu" sign, there is this black screen. (Hence, I can't login)
All I can do is, ctrl + alt + f3 and get into the console.
So after searching in the internet, I uninstalled lubuntu-desktop using

sudo apt-get remove lxde

sudo apt-get remove lubuntu-desktop

(or something of that sort after logging into the console.)

I tried reinstalling ubuntu desktop, lightdm and nvidia drivers but still nothing.

How can I get it back to work?

Also, how can I safely install a desktop environments?

I remember having a hard time long time ago as well, with Gnome. :S

**Problem 2 :**
This old laptop can boot into Ubuntu 18.04, 15.04, Archlinux and Windows 10. 
The home folder on Ubuntu 18.04 is encrypted with ecryptfs. (Or maybe even LUKS? I'm not too sure)
How do I access it from ubuntu 15.04?

Comment: After starting up and going into a terminal screen (e.g., Ctrl + Alt + F3) can you do `startx` and tell us what error message you get?

Comment: Oh, I managed to get it to work by installing gdm. With it I was able to get into the login screen - but was baffled as to why it would still give black screen. It worked as soon as I changed the desktop environment by clicking on the circle like button.